# Maria DB - Is there a point in indexing each uniq index cols separately?

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, select

We are running 10.2.44-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server. Right now I am creating tables with this structure

```
Primary('id')
UniqueIndex('colA', 'colB', 'colc');
Index('cola')
Index('colb')
Index('colc')
```

I was wondering, does it make sense to have those indexes for each column? Those columns can be legitimately queried on their own like `Select cola` or `JOIN ON cola` but does the server know to use the index on those situations or does it use the unique index since those cols are already in there?

Comment: *does it make sense to have those indexes for each column?* Only one index would be used.

Comment: `Index('cola')` is a redundant index to `UniqueIndex('colA', 'colB', 'colc')` because it's a sequential subset of it, and therefore is a waste of write operations. `UniqueIndex('colA', 'colB', 'colc')` can be used for all the same use cases as `Index('cola')`, so `Index('cola')` is not needed.

Comment: @J.D. It depends.. for example, if colB/colC is long string-type column then its presence in the index will increase the amount of disk reads during index scanning dramatically.

Comment: @Akina That's a different question of discussion than OP's original question though. My answer is under the assumption OP has a use case for operating on `colA`, `colB`, and `colC` all at the same time and therefore needs an index on all 3. Therefore *also* having the individual index on `colA` is redundant. But either way, both indexes shouldn't ever be needed concurrently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume you are using InnoDB, the default storage engine.

The indexes on individual columns `colb` and `colc` may be used in a query searching on those columns. The three-column index cannot be used for such queries:

```
SELECT ... WHERE colb = ?

SELECT ... WHERE colc = ?
```

The index on `cola` is *almost* redundant with the unique index on three columns, but not quite redundant. The reason is that InnoDB secondary indexes implicitly have the primary key appended to the columns you name. So you really have indexes as if you had defined them as follows:

```
Primary(`id`)
UniqueIndex(`colA`, `colB`, `colc`) with extra `id`
Index(`cola`, `id`)
Index(`colb`, `id`)
Index(`colc`, `id`)
```

The `id` in the unique index isn't used for uniqueness, but it is present in the secondary index.

Now suppose you have a query like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE cola = ? ORDER BY id
```

It would be able to use the index on `cola`, `id` and be guaranteed the sort order is a no-op because of the order of `id` in that index. So it avoids the need for a filesort.

But the unique index on `cola`, `colb`, `colc` is not in the same sort order, so the `ORDER BY id` would require a filesort.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It really cleared things for me.